The bot doesn't work with commands. [discord.py]
I'm trying to learn about discord.py and create bots on Discord, but I'm having a curious problem because my bot responds to commands in DMs, but it doesn't respond in the server channel even though I've given it permissions. Can help me to fix this?
My code
# Importe a biblioteca dotenv
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Carregue as variáveis de ambiente do arquivo .env
load_dotenv()

# Acesse as variáveis de ambiente
discord_key = os.getenv("DISCORD_KEY")

# Prefixo dos comandos do bot
prefix = "!"

# Definição dos intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True  # Habilita o intent para mensagens
intents.guilds = True    # Habilita o intent para servidores
intents.members = True   # Habilita o intent para membros
intents.reactions = True # Habilita o intent para reações

# Inicialização do bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)

# Evento para imprimir uma mensagem quando o bot estiver online
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} está online!')

# Comando simples para dizer olá
@bot.command()
async def ola(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Olá, {ctx.author.mention}!')

# Comando para somar dois números
@bot.command()
async def soma(ctx, num1: int, num2: int):
    resultado = num1 + num2
    await ctx.send(f'A soma de {num1} e {num2} é {resultado}.')

# Roda o bot
bot.run(discord_key)


My log on docker
 docker-compose up
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container bot-python_app-1  Created                                                                 0.0s
Attaching to python_app-1
python_app-1  | 2024-04-10 10:39:08 WARNING  discord.ext.commands.bot Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected.
python_app-1  | 2024-04-10 10:39:08 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
python_app-1  | 2024-04-10 10:39:11 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: f12d4510255ae67e973c93462642f397).


My url to invite bot to server

https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=1226960931527987281&permissions=8&scope=applications.commands+bot+messages.read+guilds+applications.commands.permissions.update

Privileged Intents

This answer might solve your issue.

You forgot to add the intent to send messages on servers.
python_app-1  | 2024-04-10 10:39:08 WARNING  discord.ext.commands.bot Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected.

As you can see, your docker log also points out that the message intent is missing.
intents.message_content = True 

This line should fix your problem
